# Drop down in Bootstrap linked items

Tags: list, twitter-bootstrap-3, dropdown

I have a Bootstrap list (linked items) on my page, like this one:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">One</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Two</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Three</a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to include a drop down at the bottom of the list. So far I have not been able to achieve that, nor finding an adequate answer on Google or SO.

Tried out this solution, but the drop down didn't become an integrated part of the list:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><?php echo $year; ?>
<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <?php while ($row = $myvar->fetch()) {;?>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><?php echo $row['year']; ?> </a></li>
  <?php } ?> 
</ul>
```

Comment: have u take div with class dropdown as parent ?

Comment: see http://www.bootply.com/keRCt11XVj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the dropdown inside a `<div class="list-group-item">`...

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">One</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Two</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Three</a>
  <div class="list-group-item">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="" data-toggle="dropdown">Link <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">text</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/gOI82wBTTf

Answer (score 0):

take parent `<div>` with class dropdown and try

For Example

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><?php echo $year; ?> <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <?php while ($row = $myvar->fetch()) {;?>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><?php echo $row['year']; ?> </a></li>
      <?php } ?> 
    </ul>
</div>
```